# insert "+" symbol into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

- I have a list of phone numbers in mysql database.
- The phone numbers are in "234808090987" format.
- I want to alter it to become "+234808980898"  How do i alter the
  database to add the + symbol to each row. I have upto 1500 numbers in
  the database

  INSERT INTO `aspilos_log`(`category2`) VALUES ('2');

the above didn't work

or is there a way i can add + symbol while printing the number from the database

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="db",
user="root",
passwd="aspilos",
database="aspilos_log",
auth_plugin="mysql_native_password"
)
 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 mycursor.execute("SELECT PHONE_NUMBER FROM category2")
 results = mycursor.fetchall()
 for i in zip(*results):
 number = list(i)
 print (number)
```

- i mean the output of the above is (23460798509004, 23480987666556,
  23498077685449),
- Is there a way i can print it as (+2349084998883993, +23409878929888,
  +234576990046989)

Comment: A database should not care about how to *format* items, that is what the template/rendering engine should do.

Comment: *I have a list of phone numbers in mysql database.* What is the datatype of the column where they're stored in? *I want to alter it to become "+234808980898"* Do you want to **store** the numbers with leading plus sign, or you want to **retrieve** the values from the table with this leading plus sign only?

Comment: either ways. I initially want to store it with with leading + sign, if that can't be done, i will like to retrieve the values of the table with leading + sign

Comment: @dMd: but that is not something that a database should care about. A database is specialized in storing, retrieving and aggregating data. Not in *presenting* data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ikr, mysql is not accepting plus sign whenever i'm trying to save it. That's what prompted my question not the retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('+', PHONE_NUMBER) FROM category2
```

Moreover, I'll suggest not to store anything that you might use to format the phone_number. At present it's '+' sign that you need to use to format, what if in future this symbol changes, and now you need to format the phone number with any new symbol?

This might cause you pain.